# make thumbnail croped by half html

Tags: html, css

hello im using bootstrap3, 
i have 3 inline thumbnail with image and i want to the last thumbnail got crop by half.
can some of you help me to solve this proplem guys.
i tried with overflow hidden. but the height of cropped thumbnail with the normal thumbnail become not the same

my css is like this

```
.imageList{
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-top: 10px
    }
```

heres the link for my js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/px3t08jf/3/

Comment: got update my jsfiddle, please look it guys

Comment: could you please explain it clearly what need to be fixed.

Comment: Use images in background instead img tag, this way it would be easy to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.imageList{
  display: flex;
  width:750px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.thumbnail {
  flex:0 0 45%;
}

.thumbnail img {
  min-width:300px;
}

.thumbnail.crop-image {
  flex:0 1 10%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sjfxL045/

http://autoprefixer.github.io/